# remove a list of lists while iterating over it

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I know that you are not supposed to remove an element of a list while iterating over it but I have to. 
I'm trying to iterate over a list of lists and if I find a value in a list of my lists i need to remove it. 
This is what I've tried so far.

```
dict[["A1","A2"],
     ["B1","B2"],
     ["C1","C2"]]

for i in range(len(dict)):
    if dict[i][0]=="A1":
        dict.pop(i)
```

But it's giving me an error of out of range.
How can I do it with list comprehensions or any other approach?

Comment: Why do you have a list of lists apparently named `dict`?!

Comment: Try to have a new list and apply changes to that

Comment: why do you "have to"?

Comment: Please provide us runnable code snippet. As you can see, even code highlighting shows something is wrong.

Comment: I believe you are missing a paren: `for i in range(len(dict)):`

Comment: `dict` is a reserved keyword, no variable should be named like that.

Comment: The problem (besides the missing parens) was a missing quote, which I added back. `dict` is not reserved; it's a builtin. Your code will compile fine if you shadow it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
old = [["A1","A2"], ["B1","B2"], ["C1","C2"]]
new = [x for x in old if x[0] != "A1"]
```

Comment: You can even mutate the original list in place by assigning back to the unbounded slice of itself: `old[:] = [x for x in old if x[0] != "A1"]` will mutate the original `list` (important in the case where the original `list` was passed as an argument, or may otherwise be referenced from many places and the mutations must be seen by all referents).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: yes, feasible, but mostly a bad idea.

Comment: Bad idea? Why? I mean, in general, it's not what you want to do, and it gains you little, but it's not actively harmful in the general case. A little squicky in the case of mutating function arguments (side effects are squicky, particularly if you're trying to write quasi-functional code), but in other cases, it makes sense. If there is some module global `list` for instance, and it must be mutated, doing so not-in-place will cause code that did `from mymodule import mylist` to lose the association with `mymodule`'s `mylist`. Same goes for locally cached referenced to class variables, etc.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: sure, like any other tool, `[:]` has its uses, but that's not something I'd recommend or even mention to a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You will get an exception. Create a new list as a copy.

```
>>> disallowed = [1, 2, 3]
>>> my_list = [ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [3, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8, 2] ]
>>> filtered_list = [[y for y in x if y not in disallowed] for x in my_list]
>>> print filtered_list
[[4, 5, 6, 7], [4, 5, 8, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually delete from a list while you iterate over it, provided you to it backwards (so deletion only affects higher indices which you have already seen during this iteration):

```
data = [["A1","A2"],
        ["B1","B2"],
        ["C1","C2"]]

for i, pair in reversed(data):
    if pair[0] == 'A1':
        del data[i]
```